# Creating a new index in DynamoDB with existing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a doubt. For example, I created an Index on a DynamoDB table and insert three elements. And now my index looks like this:

[image: Dynamo Index with three elements]

Now with the three elements in the table I create a new Index on DynamoDB which look like this:

[image: Second Index on DynamoDB]

And what I see is the following problem (my theory):

The size of the first index has the three items but the second index does not have the three elements. I did this test because I have a table with 15 million items and need to recreate or add a new index. The problem is if the index does not have the elements of the table that already existed that means if my application use the new index only can find new inserts after the creation of the index.

The question is:

- My Theory is correct?
- Is there a way to fill the new index with the data that already existed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your theory is incorrect:

`Backfilling: For each item in the table, DynamoDB determines which set of attributes to write to the index based on its projection (KEYS_ONLY, INCLUDE, or ALL). It then writes these attributes to the index.` 
From:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating

The creation of a global index after the creation of your table don't cause the loss of data. However Sparse index can cause that.
Let's put in an example:

Let's say you have a table with Primary key = email and you create a global index with Primary key as region (even after inserting some data).

Item_1 : `{ email: test@test.com, region: USA}` Will be inserted in both your table and GSI

Item_2 : `{ email: test@test.com, age: 21}` Will be inserted only in your table

Actually this is a very useful feature, you can learn more here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html

Comment: According to what you say and what the documentation says the GSI will only have the items where the items contains the primary or sort key attributes. My only fear is I don't know why in the size of the new index is 0kb. It is supposed that it should have been filled with the items that had the primary and sort key, but I don't see it reflected in the index tab.

Comment: Are you sure the data type of the attribute value does  match the data type of the index key schema data type ?

Comment: Yeah, that match. I'm will wait six hours because I look amazon update the info every that interval. If my index change the size I will accept your answer :) !